# Как преобразовать объект String в объект типа Date?

Tags: java

У меня есть строка "Tue Jan 05 15:06:26 MSK 2021". Как получить из этой строки объект типа Date?

```
        String str = "Tue Jan 05 15:06:26 MSK 2021";
        SimpleDateFormat d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        Date sd = d2.parse(str);
```

Данный код вызывает java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jan 05 15:06:26 MSK 2021". В чём ошибка?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно распарсить дату и время?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1168609/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найден ответ, спасибо:

```
SimpleDateFormat d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```